# insert data from xml column into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a xml column that look like

```
SET @XMLData = '<ArrayOfEntityNested xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.Bijak">
                   <EntityNested>
                       <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto">1</Id>
                       <Date xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">0001-01-01T00:00:00</Date>
                       <Description xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">deesc</Description>
                       <Number xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak" i:nil="true" />
                   </EntityNested>
                 </ArrayOfEntityNested>'
```

I need insert data from the XML into a temp table.

[here](http://www.venkateswarlu.co.in/SQLServer/How_to_read_data_from_XML_string.aspx)

For this I use from following code. But it's not working, and it's not inserting any data into temp table.

```
--Variables Decleration
DECLARE @XMLData VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @idoc INT

-- Creating Temporary Table
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
(
    REC_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Id] INT,
    [Date] VARCHAR(50),
    [Number] VARCHAR(50),
);

--Case 1
SET @XMLData = '<ArrayOfEntityNested xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.Bijak">
                   <EntityNested>
                      <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto">1</Id>
                      <Date xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">0001-01-01T00:00:00</Date>
                      <Number xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak" i:nil="true" />
                   </EntityNested>
                </ArrayOfEntityNested>
                               '
--Reading Data from XML and inserting into Temp Table
EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XMLData

INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE
   SELECT * 
   FROM OpenXML(@idoc,'/ArrayOfEntityNested/EntityNested', 1)
        WITH #TEMP_TABLE

EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

--Displaying data from Temp Table
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE
DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE;
```

But that doesn't work, if xml format correct might look like :

```
SET @XMLData = '<ArrayOfEntityNested>
                   <EntityNested>
                      <Id>1</Id>
                      <Date>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Date>
                      <Description>deesc</Description>
                      <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
                      <IsDeleted>false</IsDeleted>
                      <LoadingPermitTruckId>7541</LoadingPermitTruckId>
                    </EntityNested>
                 </ArrayOfEntityNested>'
```

then it works.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all - please **use appropriate data types!** If your source data is XML - why aren't you using the `XML` datatype?

Also, if you have a `Date` in your table - why isn't that a `DATE` or `DATETIME` type?? And why is the `Number` a `VARCHAR(50)` ??

Makes no sense......

Then: you're not looking at the XML namespaces that are present in the XML document - but you **must**!

At lastly - I would recommend using the native XQuery support instead of the legacy, deprecated `sp_xml_preparedocument` / `OpenXML` approach....

Seems much easier, much clearer to me...

Use this:

```
-- variable declaration
DECLARE @XMLData XML

-- creating temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
(
    REC_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Id] INT,
    [Date] DATETIME2(3),
    [Number] INT
);
```

and then use proper XQuery statements, **including the XML namespaces** to handle the data:

```
SET @XMLData = '<ArrayOfEntityNested xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.Bijak">
                    <EntityNested>
                       <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto">1</Id>
                       <Date xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">0001-01-01T00:00:00</Date>
                       <Number xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak" i:nil="true" />
                    </EntityNested>
                    <EntityNested>
                       <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto">42</Id>
                       <Date xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">2013-12-22T14:45:00</Date>
                       <Number xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak">373</Number>
                    </EntityNested>
                 </ArrayOfEntityNested>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.Bijak' AS ns1,
                'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto' AS ns2,
                'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Gbms.Dto.VirginBijak' AS ns3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE(ID, Date, Number)
   SELECT
  xc.value('(ns2:Id)[1]', 'int'),
  xc.value('(ns3:Date)[1]', 'DateTime2'),
  xc.value('(ns3:Number)[1]', 'int')
   FROM 
  @XmlData.nodes('/ns1:ArrayOfEntityNested/ns1:EntityNested') AS xt(xc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @idoc int

DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)

SET @doc ='
<OutLookContact>
<Contact FirstName="Asif" LastName="Ghafoor" EmailAddress1="asifghafoor@my.web.pk" />
<Contact FirstName="Rameez" LastName="Ali" EmailAddress1="rameezali@my.web.pk" />
</OutLookContact>'

--Create an internal representation of the XML document.

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(FirstName VARCHAR(250),LastName VARCHAR(250),Email1 VARCHAR(250))  

INSERT INTO @Temp(FirstName,LastName,Email1)



SELECT *

FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/OutLookContact/Contact',1)

WITH (FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50),EmailAddress1 varchar(50))


select FirstName,LastName,Email1 from @Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be a lot easier if you try to use a tool called pentaho. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaho
it is an open source tool which is used for data integration.you can create a database connection from  mysql or oracle to it and do the transformation.it is easy to use.