# Extract information from XML to SQL Server temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am working with some XML and I have an issue.

The xml looks like this:

```
<tagvalues>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Barcode</tag>
    <value>True</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.DateStampFirstScale</tag>
    <value>20180111</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.DateStampLastScale</tag>
    <value>20180111</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Dot</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Hangtab</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.Deviation</tag>
    <value>0</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationHigh</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationLimitHigh</tag>
    <value>0</value>
  </tagvalue>
</tagvalues>
```

and currently I'm getting the data with this code:

```
@data.value('/tagvalues[1]/tagvalue[3]/value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the order is changed, which means that I have to reconfigure it again.

Is it not possible to convert the XML text into an temp table like so:

```
Tag                                     Value
--------------------------------------------------
Data.Barcode                            TRUE
Data.DateStampFirstScale                20180111
Data.DateStampLastScale                 20180111
Data.Dot                                FALSE
Data.Hangtab                            FALSE
Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.Deviation          0
Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationHigh      FALSE
Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationLimitHigh 0
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866333/insert-data-from-xml-column-into-temp-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the XQuery.. `.nodes()`

```
select n.value('tag[1]', 'varchar(max)') [Tag],
       n.value('value[1]', 'varchar(max)') [Value]
from @xml.nodes('tagvalues/tagvalue') as p(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
DECLARE @XML xml;
SET @XML = 
'<tagvalues>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Barcode</tag>
    <value>True</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.DateStampFirstScale</tag>
    <value>20180111</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.DateStampLastScale</tag>
    <value>20180111</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Dot</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Hangtab</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.Deviation</tag>
    <value>0</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationHigh</tag>
    <value>False</value>
  </tagvalue>
  <tagvalue>
    <tag>Data.Scale_x.Scale_0.DeviationLimitHigh</tag>
    <value>0</value>
  </tagvalue>
</tagvalues>'

SELECT X.N.value('(tag/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS Tag,
       X.N.value('(value/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/tagvalues/tagvalue') X(N);
```