# How to load Dynamic XML data in table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below XML. And i want to load into temp table dynamically. 
When i have tried to load it static way. Its loaded perfectly now when i trying to do it dynamically with pivot it is giving only one row ( Max or min values not all.)

XML1:

```html
'<ArrayOpp>
  <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing1</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing1</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
  </Opp>
    <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing2</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing2</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
  </Opp>
  </ArrayOpp>'
```

Result:

```
ID  Type    OppoType    CategoryName    SubCategoryName Effort
1   Testing Other       Testing1        Testing1        1000
2   Testing Other       Testing2        Testing2        2000
```

And If the XML Add one more Node: Cost

XML:2
[enter image description here][1]

```
'<ArrayOpp>
  <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing1</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing1</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
    <Cost>12.00</Cost>
  </Opp>
    <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing2</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing2</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
    <Cost>12.00</Cost>
  </Opp>
  </ArrayOpp>'
```

Result:

```
ID  Type    OppoType    CategoryName    SubCategoryName Effort Cost
1   Testing Other       Testing1        Testing1        1000   12.00
2   Testing Other       Testing2        Testing2        2000   12.00
```

So could you please let me know how i can do this????

Comment: Please avoid pictures and add your XML for copy and paste. We do not like to type this in...

Comment: Sorry. Beginner on stack overflow Just added the xml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be I get this wrong, but I cannot see any need for a dynamic approach (*dynamic sql*?), neither for `PIVOT()`.

This works for both without any problems:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Comment VARCHAR(100),TheXml XML);

INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('XML1','<ArrayOpp>
  <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing1</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing1</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
  </Opp>
    <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing2</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing2</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
  </Opp></ArrayOpp>')
,('XML2','<ArrayOpp>
  <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing1</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing1</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
    <Cost>12.00</Cost>
  </Opp>
    <Opp>
    <ID>1251</ID>
    <Type>Testing</Type>
    <OppoType>Other</OppoType>
    <CategoryName>Testing2</CategoryName>
    <SubCategoryName>Testing2</SubCategoryName>
    <Effort>1200.00</Effort>
    <Cost>12.00</Cost>
  </Opp>
  </ArrayOpp>');

SELECT m.ID
      ,m.Comment 
      ,op.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') AS opp_ID
      ,op.value('(Type/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS opp_Type
      ,op.value('(OppoType/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS opp_OppoType
      ,op.value('(CategoryName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS opp_CategoryName
      ,op.value('(SubCategoryName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS opp_SubCategoryName
      ,op.value('(Effort/text())[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS opp_Effort
      ,op.value('(Cost/text())[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS opp_Cost
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY m.TheXml.nodes('ArrayOpp/Opp') A(op);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.But here i need to select the column name dynamically. As in 2nd XML you can see cost column is introduced so like that i can not predict what will be the next column in next XML. So how i can fetch the column name dynamically from XML and insert into the table . And in one go i'll get only one set of node or columns in XML.

Comment: @Bhishmasingh I do not understand, what you mean with *And in one go i'll get only one set of node or columns in XML*... If you want to give a column a name (column caption or header), this must be written litteraly, no dynamic setting is allowed here. The only chance is dynamically written SQL and `EXEC()`. But this will not make you happy in any case. Another chance is to read all nodes in an *EAV-List* and use some kind of `PIVOT` to get this tabular. But again you'd have to know all column names in advance... What is your final goal?

Comment: I thought we could make it dynamic but as you said we need to know the column names in advance so that clarifies my doubt. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bhishmasingh, Well, this *can* be done dynamically, as long as you know, that all the nodes are situated below `/ArrayOpp/Opp`. You cannot predict the type, so you must return the value as string. But the biggest problem will be, that the consumer has to deal with a resultset not known in advance. There will be one point, where you have to deal with unknown column names. There are workarounds (e.g. add the column names as *first line* in a CSV format). But in order to help you, I do not know enough about your actual case... Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to load XML data to temp table:

[Static Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866333/insert-data-from-xml-column-into-temp-table)

For dynamic load try the below one:

[Dynamic Load](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185376/t-sql-dynamically-import-xml-into-tables-sql-server-2014)

Comment: Only Static ways are available there